# dd boot partition to external drive

Tags: boot-issues

I used dd to copy boot and root partition to lvm on an external hard disk. My `lsblk` looks like below now.

```
$ lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk
├─sda1               8:1    0    2T  0 part /var/share/samba
└─sda2               8:2    0  1.7T  0 part
  ├─disk2-lv--root 254:0    0   40G  0 lvm  /
  ├─disk2-lv--nfs  254:1    0   60G  0 lvm  /nfs-share
  └─disk2-lv--boot 254:2    0  512M  0 lvm  /boot
mmcblk0            179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1        179:1    0  256M  0 part
└─mmcblk0p2        179:2    0 29.5G  0 part
```

Whenever I took out the sd card and try to boot: It displays "GPT no boot device". I'm sure it uses root fs from external drive but boot drive doesn't engage during boot up. Seems I misconfigured my system.

I have below entry in my `/boot/config.txt`

```
initramfs initramfs.gz
```

and my `/boot/cmdline.txt` file reads

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mapper/disk2-lv--root rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait noswap=1
```

Comment: What dd command did you use?  I don't see any of the partition level information like the partition labels?

Comment: @SimonBanks I used `sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 of=/dev/disk2/lv-boot bs=1M`

Comment: The SD card is [MBR formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record).  GPT is a much newer system.  The easiest way to do this is to format the drive MBR, create the two partitions, format the partitions appropriately (1st = vfat, 2nd = ext4), and then copy the contents in file wise.  If you really insist on using `dd`, you have to copy the entire card as one big lump (`mmcblk0`, no `pN`) to the hard disk overwriting any formatting on it, *not* a pre-existing partition on the hard drive.

Comment: @goldilocks thank you for your answer, if you put the above remark as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not boot a Pi from a GPT partitioned disk.

(Well strictly this is theoretically possible, but would require a custom image with GPT support.)